# php extract text between nth and nth character

Tags: php

How can I use php to get the sting bewteen the 7th and 8th /

```
http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2015/01/01/england/premier-league/stoke-city-fc/manchester-united-fc/1703889/?ICID=HP_MS_01_01
```

so the above would grab england

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$url = 'http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2015/01/01/england/premier-league/stoke-city-fc/manchester-united-fc/1703889/?ICID=HP_MS_01_01';
$tokens = explode('/', $url);
echo $tokens[7]; // 'england'
```

PHP docs for [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

php function explode does the exact thing
learn more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$n = 7; $m = 8;

$str = "http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2015/01/01/england/premier-league/stoke-city-fc/manchester-united-fc/1703889/?ICID=HP_MS_01_01";

$a = explode('/', $str);

echo $a[$n];
```

Like this, you can get it for any random value of n and m.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD